# Is the Stack Exchange performance page up to date?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com

Hidden away in the "About" section of Stack Exchange (but not Stack Overflow), is a page called "Performance" (https://stackexchange.com/performance) which lists all sorts of server statistics. I find all these statistics interesting, but I've gotten curious about the accuracy as the values do not seem to change. Is the page out of date or has Stack Exchange just not experienced much growth?

Comment: Back when Nick Craver was still making fast things for Stack Exchange it was more accurate to follow his Twitter feed. It had the real nifty details now and then.

Comment: Marketing pages are like that on many sites. Put up some big number statistics and perhaps update them every few years when someone happens to notice they look stale

Comment: TL;DR: no it is not up to date. It's a static promo page that nobody really cares about anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in [2014 that page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141015061645/https://stackexchange.com/performance) claimed

> 560 million pages (sic) views per month.

Many of the numbers were the same in early [2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150105034201/http://stackexchange.com/performance) but some such as CPU usage on the SQL servers had increased - from 4% to 8%, even as the number of queries per day had reduced. The typo above had been corrected though.

By [2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170522222326/https://stackexchange.com/performance) we're up to

> 1.3 Billion page views per month

And the hardware has had memory upgrades too.

And that's pretty much where we've stayed since 2017 since 2017's page is basically identical to today's page. So if there have been changes since 2017 they are not recorded there.

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth was also removed from the programming stack list in 2018, but there haven't been additional changes to that page since then.